# Update Insert Delete in MDS

Tags: ssis, batch-processing, business-intelligence

SSIS Package [SSIS Data flow for staging I have a quick question related to Insert, Update and Delete in MDS.

I have created an SSIS package which loads the data into staging and from staging it transfers it into MDS production tables. But when I run the import batch multiple times it does not recognizes the fact that it's the same member and  rather it just imports the batch as duplicates and assigns a different code.

I wonder if I'm missing something in my SSIS package or I need to setup a business rule that would trigger the update of the existing member if any changes.

Comment: Incremental model needs business rule. Simplest one I can suggest is, to read the last `ID` from staging table and modify your fetch query `where` ID is greater than last staging ID.

Comment: Please provide a little more information on your process. I guess something is missing in your description: the screenshot you provided includes a truncation of the tables - so there shouldn't be any duplicates anywhere... so, WHERE do you have the duplicates? And are there any other steps before or after your SSIS? Or triggers on the DB? And could you provide some Info on WHAT is exedcuted in the steps in your SSIS?

Comment: The duplicates are showing up in the mds tables after you run the package. It does not recognize that the same member already exists so what it does it assigns a different code and inserts the members as duplicates.